# ColdFusion: how to check 15 days past the submitted date?

Tags: coldfusion

I saved several  accounts in the database. I want to email the accountsdd that have been expired for 15 days.  In another word,  if the submitted day (date format: mm-dd-yyyy) is 15 days older from today's date then send an email.  How do I do it? Any info is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are storing your dates as DATES, or - as you say - a string formatted in `mm-dd-yyyy`. If it really is the latter, you should consider changing it.

Answer (score 2):

you would want to use the `dateDiff` function

```
<cfif dateDiff('d',submittedDate,now()) GT 15>
```

If your date is really stored as `mm-dd-yyyy` instead of a date/time object then you would need to use the `createODBCDate` function

```
<cfif dateDiff('d',CreateODBCDate(submittedDate),now()) GT 15>
```

If you're looking to pull all accounts via a query this would work. This would work on MSSQL

```
SELECT relevant, columns
FROM myTable
WHERE dateDiff(d,submittedDate,getDate()) > 15
```

Comment: FYI, in terms of querying, using database functions like that [usually prevents the database from using indexes](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/). (Old article, but the concept still applies). Better to restructure the expression to avoid it (see example in [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17929194/104223) ).

Answer (score 0):

Without more details (database type, data types, etectera) this is just an educated guess. But it sounds like you are asking how to find all records that were submitted exactly fifteen days ago, regardless of the time. For example if the date and time now is July 29, 2013 08:49 AM, you want to retrieve all records submitted on July 14, 2013 (any time between 12 midnight and 11:59:59 PM).

A query with a simple range comparison should do the trick. Note: While Matt's suggestion of [`dateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) (or your database's version of it) would also work, using functions in that manner often [prevent the database from leveraging indexes](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/). So it is preferable to use a more index friendly expression, like:

```
<cfset fifteenDaysAgo = dateAdd("d", -15, now())>
<cfquery ...>
   SELECT  emailAddress
   FROM    yourTable
   WHERE   submittedDate >= <cfqueryparam value="#fifteenDaysAgo#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
   AND     submittedDate < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, fifteenDaysAgo)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
</cfquery>
```

Then it is just a matter of using the query results to send out your emails.